# How can I map properties conditionally with MapStruct 1.2?

Tags: mapping, conditional-statements, mapstruct

Is it possible with MapStruct 1.2 to map a source property with a specific value to a specific different value in the target?

I think about something like this:

```
public abstract class JiraKpmMapper {
    @Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "mySource.propA", target = "myTarget.propX")
    })
    @ValueMappings({
        @ValueMapping(source = "ABC", target = "XYZ"),
        @ValueMapping(source = "123", target = "789")
    })
    public abstract MyTarget source2Target(final MySource mySource);

}
```

So that when MapStruct sees during the mapping that when mySource.propA has the value "ABC" myTarget.propX needs to be set to value "XYZ" and so forth.

To be more precisely, I even want something more elaborated:
The target should be a class haven three properties in which the resulting target value must be split into.
For instance, if mySource.propA has the value "ABC" the target myTarget should get a value like "V01.123.456.AB". This value in turn shall be split up in a preValue, a middleValue and an endValue:

preValue = "V01"

middleValue = "123.456"

endValue = "AB"

whereby there's no property holding the complete result string.

That's why I already wrote a custom mapper and I tell the MyMapper to use it via

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = MyCustomMapper.class)
```

This works so far but I can't achieve it to tell the MyCustomMapper to put "V01.123.456.AB" into the target when the souzrce comes with "ABC".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't really do that with MapStruct. The `@ValueMapping` annotation is for mapping of `Enum`(s).

In order to achieve what you are looking for you would need to do that in `@BeforeMapping` or `@AfterMapping`.

For example you can do something like:

```
@Mapper
public interface JiraKpmMapper {

    @BeforeMapping
    default void beforeMapping(@MappingTarget MyTarget target, MySource source) {
        if (source.getPropY().equals("ABC") {
            target.setPropX("V01.123.456.AB");
        }
    }

    @Mapping(target = "propX", ignore = true) // This is now mapped in beforeMapping
    MyTarget source2Target(final MySource mySource);
}
```

Your custom mapper then should have an `@AfterMapping`. Where you would convert the `propX` into your class. You can even do this as part of the `@BeforeMapping` I wrote and directly create your class (or invoke the method that does the conversion from `String` into a class)

Comment: That do pretty what I intend to to. I had similar to with another property but then I have to put the value into a property of a reference mebmer of the target class. In this case I have to do the stuff in '@AfterMapping because otherwise the referenced object is either null or if I create it manually with the default contructor it's gone after MapStruct completed its work. 
Furthermore doing what you suggested is better done in '@AfterMapping because I must buffered the target value in some property of the target class when of splitting up the source value in '@BeforeMapping.

Comment: If you do ignore on the property then MapStruct should not overwrite anything. In any case it is up to you to decide which point is the best for your conversion. I don't quite know all your details.

Answer (score 11):

you can do something like this

```
@Mapping(target = "myTarget.propX",expression="java(mySource.getPropA().equals(\"Abc\")?"\"V01.123.456.AB\":\"\")")
```