# How to use mapstruct in Spring Boot app, to map a field with one condition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I'm using mapstruct to map 2 Java objects in a Spring Boot project.

And I have this mapping:

```
@Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id"),
        @Mapping(target = "name", source = "name"),
        @Mapping(target = "detail", source = "detail"),
})
@Named("fromInfoToDetails")
abstract AccountDetails toDetails(AccountInfo from);

@IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "fromInfoToDetails")
public abstract List<AccountDetails> toAccountDetails(List<AccountInfo> accountInfos);
```

Now I want to add 2 new fields in `AccountInfo`: `type` (`String`) and `isOwner` (`boolean`) and one field in `AccountDetails`: `type` (`String`) but this field is optional, so frontend will receive this field only with a condition. If `isOwner` is true then `type` from `AccountInfo` will be mapped in `type` from `AccountDetails` and if `isOnwer` is `false`, nothing will happen, the frontend will not receive the `type` field. How to modify the above code to map these fields? I need only the mapping.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@BeforeMapping` annotation in a default or protected method.

Please refer to: [How can I map properties conditionally with MapStruct 1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067870/how-can-i-map-properties-conditionally-with-mapstruct-1-2)

and mapstruct documentation: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after